# Styling card field text boxes in PayPal Advanced Checkout

Tags: css, paypal

I'm integrating the PayPal Advanced Checkout. PayPal led us to believe that we could make the card field text boxes look the same as the ones on our website, but the CSS they allow is very limited. See integration doc below.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/customize/card-field-style/

I cannot find a way to use simple CSS styles like background and border etc.

If anyone has integrated with PayPal Advanced Checkout previously, please tell me if there is a way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We struggled with the same issue, but eventually achieved a suitable solution.  Following is an example of how our existing fields are styled in conjunction with the cardField components of PayPal's Advanced Checkout:

[image: Sample card fields]

The basics of the provided styling options:

```
const cardStyle = {
  'input': {
    'font-family': 'Arial',
    'font-size': '14px',
    'line-height': '1',
    'padding': '6px 8px',
  },
  '.invalid': {
    'color': 'purple',
  },
};
```

The containers:

```
<div id="card-form" class="card_container">
  <div id="card-number-container"></div>
  <div id="card-expiry-container"></div>
  <div id="card-cvv-container"></div>
  <button id="card-submit-button" type="button">
    Pay now by Card
    <i class="fad fa-credit-card-front fa-2x"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

The CSS for the containers:

```
#card-number-field-container { width: 354px; height: 40px; }
#card-expiry-field-container { float: left; width: 170px; height: 40px; }
#card-cvv-field-container { float: right; width: 170px; height: 40px; margin-right: 6px; }
```

The statement from the PayPal docs provided by the OP indicates much of the styling is applied to the container, not in the style element:

> Change the layout, width, height, and outer styling of the card
> fields. Modify the elements you supply as containers with your current
> stylesheets. For example, input: { border: 1px solid #333; }.

This additional PayPal doc reference

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/advanced/customize/style-card-fields/

includes additional comments regarding explicit height [and width is relevant as well]:

> Typically, input elements calculate their height from font size and
> line height (and a few other properties), but advanced credit and
> debit card payments require explicit configuration of height. Make
> sure you style the height of your containers in your stylesheets. The
> text of the field components is configured with JavaScript.

The font size, line height and padding is relevant to the container height, if the desired height is not obtained when the field renders, those settings may need to be adjusted to allow the field to fit within the specified container.

NOTE:  When the buttons render as the page loads, some unsightly activity appears. We applied opacity with a transition to the payment container with a loading image and timeout:

[CSS]

```
#payBox {   opacity: 0;   transition: opacity 1s; }
```

[jQuery]

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#loading').hide();
  $('#payBox').css('opacity', '1');
},700);
```